# Is there a way to pass a string variable to Info.plist and AndroidManifest with Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I would like  to pass a string variable to both the Info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml files in a Flutter app and I wanted to find out if there is a preferred/easiest way to do so?

Comment: Please clarify what are you trying to do, it looks like a xy problem